# factory girl - how can we access overrides passed to a method?

Tags: factory-bot, overriding

This question is related to when/how overrides work in FactoryGirl

For my specific problem, I have a organization with 'limits' attribute. The after(:create) section sets some other values and finally does a save.  The save resets the 'limits' based on logic in organization.after_save method. So I had to do update_attributes so 'limits' is set to whatever is defined in the factory girl.

This all works OK except for cases when limits is overridden by a spec.

Here is the code:

```
factory :organization do
  sequence(:name) {|n| "org#{n + $offset}" }
  .....
  limits_attributes :projectsLimit => 1, :svnEnabled => true, :deployEnabled => true
  ...
  after(:create) do | org |
    sub = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, :organization => org)
    sp = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription_plan, :subscription => sub)
    sub.subscription_plans << sp
    org.subscription = sub
    org.status = :active
    org.save
    # Since entitlements are messed up after setting sub-plan set them here.
    org.limits.update_attributes(:projectsLimit => 1, :svnEnabled => true, :deployEnabled => true)
  end
end
```

This fails when 'limits' is overridden, clearly because I am not getting the overridden attributes:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :limits_attributes => {:gitEnabled => true, :projectsLimit => 3})
```

I tried getting attributes using attributes_for, I misinterpreted attributes_for to get the values passed to 'create the organization'

```
org_attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:organization)
      puts "atts #{org_attrs}"
      org.save
      # Since entitlements are messed up after setting sub-plan set them here.
      org.limits.update_attributes(org_attrs[:limits_attributes])
```

Given that I cannot change the logic in Organization's after_save, how can I update limits if user overrides them?  Where in the flow of things are overrides applied to the models defined in FactoryGirl.

I think there might be a flaw in how I interpret what the code is doing OR the scenario I m looking to solve does not fit how FG is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect about the overridden values. org has the values set before the save (overriden or default, whatever the case). So just saving a copy before and reusing it did it.  Not sure if this is a good solution though

```
    org_limits = org.limits.dup
          org.save      
          # Since entitlements are messed up after setting sub-plan set them here.
          org.limits.update_attributes(org_limits.attributes)
```